# How to get/enable public URL for media uploaded to slack using slack API

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm using slack api to upload media to a public channel, in-response I'm getting different urls for the uploaded media including 'permalink_pulic' which seems as the public URL, but that link doesn't work.Other Links are only accessible by slack team members.

Is there any way we can enable those public_link, so that media can be accessible outside slack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general Slack files are not public, but you can open public access to them if you want.

Call the method `files.sharedPublicURL` after you uploaded it to enable public access to a Slack file via its `permalink_public` URL.

See [API documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.sharedPublicURL) for more info.

Comment: Note that you have to call both `upload` and `sharedPublicURL` with the `token` parameter set to your App's User OAuth Token (found in App -> OAuth & Permissions -> OAuth Tokens for your Workspace). I didn't realize this initially and kept getting `not_allowed_token_type`.

Answer (score 3):

To enable the public link, your app requires the **file:write:user** permission scope from the team, the team's `access_token` and the specific `file_id` you're trying to make public

Then send a request to Slack's `files.sharedPublicURL(access_token, file_id)` endpoint to receive a JSON object containing the file id.

You can use the new [Slack Events API](https://api.slack.com/events) to have Slack send your app file information, including the file id, when events as *file_created* or *file_shared* occur. [Here's a list of events Slack supports](https://api.slack.com/events)